# Can't switch tty from tty2 to tty6 in Arch Linux

Tags: linux, arch-linux, tty, nouveau, i915

I can't switch tty from tty2 to tty6 in Arch Linux. When I switch outside the GUI, the screen doesn't change (the text from tty1 remains, only the cursor disappears completely). And in the GUI (sddm, xfce4), the graphical cursor simply disappears. What I did:

1. Restarted the computer. There is no result.
2. Launched getty@tty2-tty6 services (it used to help in the VM). There is no result again.
3. Removed quiet, splash and other GRUB arguments for plymouth. The result is that it is possible to enter tty1 and GUI, but it is not possible to enter tty2-6.

I found out that tty2-6 are working for me, but they are invisible. Blindly I was able to create a file in tty2.

Laptop: Lenovo IdeaPad Y570 (yes, not new).

Video card: I don't know exactly which one works, there is Intel Integrated Graphics with i915 and NVIDIA Geforce GT 555M with nouveau.

System: Arch Linux 2022.10.01, fully updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I deleted nouveau and install offical nvidia drivers and all work!

Comment: You might want to add instructions of how did you install the Nvidia driver